# Modifying value in a numpy array conditionnal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a y_actual array of size (1250, ) and a y_predicted array of size (1250,1).
I want to compute the absolute value of the difference between y_actual and y_predicted, that I achieve with : `diff_y = np.abs(y_actual[:,] - y_predicted[:,0])`

I would like to modify values is diff_y for the specific case where y_actual is > 0 and y_predicted is < 0. Let's assume I want to multiply it by 2. I made several unsuccessful attemps, like :
`diff_y[y_actual[:,]> 0 and y_predicted[:,0] <0] *=2` but I don't succeed.
Any idea how to proceed ? Thx in advance

Comment: Side note: you could use `np.abs(y_actual - np.squeeze(y_predicted))` for the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
y_predicted = y_predicted.reshape(y_actual.shape)
diff_y = np.abs(y_actual - y_predicted)
diff_y[(y_actual> 0) & (y_predicted<0)] *=2
print(diff_y)
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot